# Getting around MediaRecorder popup "... will start capturing everything on your screen"

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I have a module that  runs animation, and when animation starts, I need to record it with the media recorder.

When I start animation, and start media recorder after that, I get pop up message ".... will start capturing everything on your screen". At this point the user need to click "start now" to allow the recording.

However, animation is already running, and it's too late to start recording when user clicks "start now".

Is there a way to know when the user clicked "start now"? Then I can start running animation after user allowed screen capturing

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you "record it with the media recorder". What you describe sounds like the media projection APIs, in which case you know when the user agrees to allow recording, because you get the callback providing the information necessary to actually begin recording.

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare. Yes, I am using projection APIs, and I see that I missed the point that in onActivityResult I have to check if resultCode == RESULT_OK. If yes, then user allowed screen sharing.